# How to assign menu items to Card inserted using TimelineManager?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

XE12 introduced TimelineManager, which allows to add Card objects into timeline. But I don't see a way how to assign menu items to the card, is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible yet in XE12. Please follow [issue 320, "Add action for static card inserted using GDK"](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=320) on our issue tracker to be updated as the GDK evolves!

Comment: Thanks! I will wait for this before integrating Glasquare to timeline.